# How to issue select query while performing batch insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file

I have a question regarding how to handle sql queries to a table while performing batch inserts to the same table.

I have an ASP.NET web application that creates lots of objects (perhaps 50000) that are inserted in  a batch fashion to a table using nHibernate. Even with the Nhibernate optimizations in place this takes up to two minutes. I perform this in a database transaction with isolation level set to read commited.

During the batch insert clients in the web application must be able to read previously created data in this table. However, they should not be able to read uncommited data. My problem is that if I use isolation level "read committed" on the select queries they time out because they are waiting for the batch insert job to finish.

Is there any way to query the database in such a way so that the query runs fast and returns all of the committed rows in the table without waiting on the batch insert job to finish? I do not want to return any uncommitted data.

I have tested setting the isolation level to "snapshot" and that seems to solve my problem, but is it the best approach?

Best regards Whimsical

Comment: Is it an option for you to split the batch into several smaller batches, so that it would take seconds, not minutes, and commit independently?

Comment: Unfortunately not, in this case it has to be all or none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SNAPSHOT isolation returns data that existed prior to the beginning of the transaction, and it doesn't a lock on the table so it doesn't block.  It also ignores other locking transactions, so in your scenario, it sounds like the best fit for you.   What it does mean is that since your data is being inserted in a batch, no data from that batch will be available to the SELECT statement until the batch completes (i.e.)

- Time 1: Dataset A exists in Table
- Time 2: Batch starts inserting dataset B into table (but doesn't commit).
- Time 3: App takes snapshot, and reads in dataset A.
- Time 4: App finishes returing dataset A (and only dataset A).
- Time 5: Batch finishes writing dataset B; Dataset A and DataSet B are
  both available in table.

Comment: Thanks. I will go  with SNAPSHOT isolation level!